# What is differences in usage between a HC-05 bluetooth module and a Zigbee HC-05 module?

Tags: bluetooth, xbee

I have seen commercial Xbee / Zigbee clones using HC-05 integrated inside.
Are they any different than regular HC-05 bluetooth modules?

- What is differences in usage between a HC-05 bluetooth module and a Zigbee HC-05 module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth and Zigbee are two different communication protocols. The Xbee clones you are talking about a called [BTbee](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/bluetooth-bee-hc05-btbeehc05-p-171.html).

As far as im aware the BTbee modules are the same hardware/firmware wise as the hc05/hc06 modules. The only difference being the BTbee modules are in the Xbee footprint, allowing you to plug them into Xbee/Zigbee sockets.

Comment: I see! That's precisely what I was wondering though, cheers! Are there any Zigbee clones that do not use Bluetooth?